# In which date format does selenium for NodeJS save the cookie expiration date?

Tags: node.js

at the moment im parsing some cookies with Selenium for NodeJS. Everything is working fine so far, but the "problem" which im facing right now is, that I don't know in which date format the cookie expiration is saved in. The result is something like this: `2145916800.861482`. Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Its a Unix Timestamp